# Show specific number of items on paragraph field

Tags: 8, forms, paragraphs

I have configured a field like this:
[image]

When I create a Node, the field shows like this:

[image]

How can I, programmatically, start this field with two elements and not have to click on the "Add pet" button?
For example:

[image]

Comment: Don't know if there is a solution in UI. In code you can do this in a hook_node_create, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259275/create-any-number-of-paragraph-fields-in-a-multiple-value-field-on-node-create-f

Comment: @4k4 thanks, it works for nodes, i needed this solution for a block too, but hook_block_create() didn't call, do you know why? I check my module name, clear cache, but didn't call it. I try with hook_entity_create() and works.

Comment: The entity type for custom blocks is block_content, so hook_block_content_create() should work.